# Arranging the leaderboards from highest balance to the lowest balance

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

There are no errors when I run this code. However, the bot does not send who has the highest balance through leaderboards. It sends who the first person who executed the command is. I just wanted to know how I can make the bot return the message through descending order. [Here's the image if you want to see what I mean.](https://gyazo.com/956cae135ba5752f91a9a3357d0e6fe0) Thanks! Database: v7.0.0

```
   if (args[0] == 'coins') {
   let coins = db.all().filter(a => a.ID.startsWith(`coins_${message.guild.id}`, { sort: '.data'}))
   let content = "";

   for (let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
   let user = client.users.cache.get(coins[i].ID.split('_')[2]).username

   content += `${i+1}. ${user} ~ ${coins[i].data}\n`

  }

   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`**${message.guild.name}'s Coin Leaderboard**\n\n${content}`)
      .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])

   message.channel.send(embed)
  }
```

Comment: Defining *"solve an issue"* in more detailed technical terms would help people understand what the problem actually is here.  Also no  mention here of what is or isn't working or any errors thrown. Suggest taking a few minutes to thoroughly read [ask]

Comment: Done! Thanks for the heads up! ;)

Comment: would be helpful to say what database library you're using

Comment: Version added :)